# Cascade delete by a foreign key does not work in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I try to delete "Lbr" table, I expect all tables will be cleared, but I get error message "the "LbrStab" table violates the foreign key constraint "FK_LbrStabTsk_LbrStab" of the "LbrStabTsk" table" why it happens? This kind of data is easily deleted in MS SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Lbr"
(
    "LbrUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Lbr" PRIMARY KEY ("LbrUid")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."LbrStab"
(
    "LbrStabUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "LbrUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_LbrStab" PRIMARY KEY ("LbrStabUid"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_LbrStab_Lbr" FOREIGN KEY ("LbrUid")
        REFERENCES public."Lbr" ("LbrUid") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."LbrTskStgs"
(
    "LbrTskStgsUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "LbrUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_LbrTskStgs" PRIMARY KEY ("LbrTskStgsUid"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_LbrTskStgs_Lbr" FOREIGN KEY ("LbrUid")
        REFERENCES public."Lbr" ("LbrUid") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."LbrTsk"
(
    "LbrTskUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "LbrTskStgsUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_LbrTsk" PRIMARY KEY ("LbrTskUid"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_LbrTsk_LbrTskStgs" FOREIGN KEY ("LbrTskStgsUid")
        REFERENCES public."LbrTskStgs" ("LbrTskStgsUid") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."LbrStabTsk"
(
    "LbrStabTskUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "LbrStabUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "LbrTskUid" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_LbrStabTsk" PRIMARY KEY ("LbrStabTskUid"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_LbrStabTsk_LbrStab" FOREIGN KEY ("LbrStabUid")
        REFERENCES public."LbrStab" ("LbrStabUid") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_FK_LbrStabTsk_LbrTsk" FOREIGN KEY ("LbrTskUid")
        REFERENCES public."LbrTsk" ("LbrTskUid") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

adding data to tables:

```
INSERT INTO public."Lbr" VALUES('48ae4e17-516a-4995-8c36-1fadfa6f098b');
INSERT INTO public."LbrStab" VALUES('74ae453f-8a0d-43f8-92bc-9c88b3fac38e','48ae4e17-516a-4995-8c36-1fadfa6f098b');

INSERT INTO public."LbrTskStgs" VALUES('8f992ae3-318e-488e-a5a5-229ebc3171cb','48ae4e17-516a-4995-8c36-1fadfa6f098b');

INSERT INTO public."LbrTsk" VALUES('09287d19-8291-4c20-8f86-daa30eed4a49', '8f992ae3-318e-488e-a5a5-229ebc3171cb');
INSERT INTO public."LbrTsk" VALUES('a36fbe06-f378-4ea7-8407-91e5e0b41f4a', '8f992ae3-318e-488e-a5a5-229ebc3171cb');
INSERT INTO public."LbrTsk" VALUES('ca37aeaa-0d6d-4966-a71e-3256adb14ff2', '8f992ae3-318e-488e-a5a5-229ebc3171cb');

INSERT INTO public."LbrStabTsk" VALUES('c552c4f2-a7dc-45cd-b542-162625bd7d41','74ae453f-8a0d-43f8-92bc-9c88b3fac38e','09287d19-8291-4c20-8f86-daa30eed4a49');
INSERT INTO public."LbrStabTsk" VALUES('c6d297e9-1639-42fa-a688-5a36c2c29711','74ae453f-8a0d-43f8-92bc-9c88b3fac38e','a36fbe06-f378-4ea7-8407-91e5e0b41f4a');
INSERT INTO public."LbrStabTsk" VALUES('4b18a2d1-6430-4521-b125-bd0d7cb846af','74ae453f-8a0d-43f8-92bc-9c88b3fac38e','ca37aeaa-0d6d-4966-a71e-3256adb14ff2');

--DELETE FROM public."Lbr" WHERE ("LbrUid" = '48ae4e17-516a-4995-8c36-1fadfa6f098b')
```

How does postgres build up the order in cascade deletion?
Why does it start deleting data from the "LbrStab" table instead of the "LbrTskStgs" table?

Comment: The issue is: `CONSTRAINT "FK_LbrStabTsk_LbrStab"  ... ON UPDATE NO ACTION   ON DELETE NO ACTION, ...` Change to `ON UPDATE NO CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE ...`

Comment: It really saves me, but why does MS SQL delete such a thing without a problem?

Comment: Because it does not follow the standard? Per docs [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):  *NO ACTION Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign key constraint violation. If the constraint is deferred, this error will be produced at constraint check time if there still exist any referencing rows. This is the default action.*. So you might see if making the FK deferrable alters the behavior. Though `ON CASCADE DELETE` seems to be what you want in any case.